# How to overcome a 422 error on gtihub while creating a repo?

Tags: java, spring-boot, github, github-api

I was trying to create a repo in GitHub through API(org.kohsuke.github). In my interface, I got a 422 error (unable to process an entity)  but the repo was created in Github.

```
GHCreateRepositoryBuilder repositoryBuilder =
     getGitHubOrganization().getRawObject().createRepository(repositoryName).private_(isPrivate).create();
```

Answer (score 0):

> **The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 422 Unprocessable Entity**
> response status code indicates that the server understands the content
> type of the request entity, and the syntax of the request entity is
> correct, but it was unable to process the contained instructions.

So I guess github understood that you wanted to create a repo but couldn't make out some of the details. Either this `org.kohsuke.github` API is outdated, or not handling the error messages very elegantly. Try to put a breakpoint in the API source code at the place where it throws the error, to see if the original error message from github contains some clues.